# PayPal PHP SDK API - Get all Transactions

Tags: php, paypal

I want to use PayPal PHP SDK API to list all my Payments/Transactions. For Sandbox Credentials I`m finally successfully, but if i switch to LIVE Credentials the Result is just:

```
{
    "count": 0
}
```

...Yes im switching to LIVE with:

```
$apiContext->setConfig(array('mode' => 'live'));
```

What could be my failure? Here is my Full Code:

```
<?php
// 1. Autoload the SDK Package. This will include all the files and classes to your autoloader
require __DIR__  . '/autoload.php';

$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
        'ABC',     // ClientID
        'DEF'      // ClientSecret
    )
);
$apiContext->setConfig(array('mode' => 'live'));

#$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
#    new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
#        'XYZ',     // ClientID
#        'XYZZ'      // ClientSecret
#    )
#);

// Test
//require 'CreatePayment.php';
//use PayPal\Api\Payment;
$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();

try {

    $params = array('count' => 10, 'start_index' => 0);

    $payments = $payment->all($params, $apiContext);
    echo $payments;
} catch (Exception $ex) {

}
```

Comment: You also need to get the clientId and secret of live too. PayPal uses different credentials for live and sanbox. Please follow instructions here: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live

Comment: Yes, for sure, but it dont work with my LIVE Credentials! Do i need to enable "Future Payments" or something else?

Comment: You just need to enable payments and thats it. Feel free to contact https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask